# Closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}$

Tags: analysis, factorial, divergent-series, bernoulli-numbers

What do you think about the closed form I found for this series?

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} = \frac{e+1}{2(e-1)}$$

I found it this way:

Take the Ramanujan's summation $C(0)$ for divergent series:

$$C(0) = -\frac{1}{2}f(0) - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{ B_{2k}}{(2k)!}f^{(2k-1)}(0)$$

Let $f(x)=e^x$ so that $f^{(2k-1)}(0)=f(0)=1$.

Now we have:

$$C(0) = -\frac{1}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

Lets now assign some value to $C(0)$, by manipulating $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^k$ one arrives to:

$$S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^k = e^1+e^2+e^3+...$$
$$\frac{1}{e}S=1+S$$
$$S=\frac{e}{1-e}$$

Now we have:

$$\frac{e}{1-e} = -\frac{1}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
$$\frac{e}{1-e} + \frac{1}{2} = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
$$\frac{e+1}{2(1-e)} = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
$$\frac{e+1}{2(e-1)} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

Comment: The only issue I see is that the series numerically converges to $0.0819767\dots$ while $\frac{e+1}{2(e-1)} = 1.081976\dots$ implying your result if off by $\color{red}{1}$

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the identity follows immediately from the definition  of [Bernoulli number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html). It si known that for $|x|<2\pi$,
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}+\frac{x}{2}-1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
so by taking $x=1$ we get the result (different from OP's)
$$\frac{3-e}{2(e-1)}=\frac{1}{e-1}+\frac{1}{2}-1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}.$$
Am I missing something?

P.S.By the way the
$$\frac{e+1}{2\left(e-1\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}x^{2k}}{(2k)!}.$$

Comment: +1 agreed. Seems the OP is asking for proof verification though, so this doesn't directly answer the OP's question. That being said, this is definitely cleaner, assuming you define the Bernoulli Numbers this way. It could be that the OP defines Bernoulli Numbers USING Ramanujan Summation though, in which case this wouldn't help (again, assuming the OP can't simply use the previously proven equivalence of the two definitions of the Bernoulli Numbers)

Answer (score 1):

What do I think? That you should take care when using Ramanujan Summation this way.

Note that:
$$\frac{e+1}{2\left(e-1\right)} =\color{red}{1}.08197670687\ldots\neq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} = \color{red}{0}.08197670687\ldots$$

Without using numerics we can already see that
$$\frac{e+1}{2\left(e-1\right)} \gt \frac{e+1}{2\left(e+1\right)} = 1/2$$ 
While we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} < \sum_{k=1}^2\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} = \frac{59}{720}<1/2$$
Proving that the two are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Taylor_series_expressions), a Taylor series is $$\coth x=\dfrac{1}{x}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{4^nB_{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n-1}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0<|x|< \pi$$  where $B_n$ is the $n$th Bernoulli number.

We can rewrite it as $$\coth x=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}(2x)^{2n}$$ So, making $x=\frac 12$ we have $$\coth\left(\frac 12\right)=\frac{e^{1/2}+e^{-1/2}}{e^{1/2}-e^{-1/2}}=\frac{e+1}{e-1}=2+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ and then $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}=\frac{3-e}{2 (e-1)}$$